# Variable declaration expected

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn React Flux by following this Video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmdPegEyyVs

This piece of code is highlighted by VS Code here

[image]

```
 import Flux from "@4geeksacademy/react-flux-dash";
     
    const export let addContact = (contact) => {
        
    }
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: should be `export const addContact = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `const` before export.
Definitely it will work out

Answer (score 1):

"export const" not "const export let"

```
import Flux from '@4geeksacademy/react-flux-dash';

export const addContact = (contact) => {};
```

Answer (score 0):

export is a keyword it can't be used as a variable choose different variable